# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right

Tags: php, mysql

I have a edit page. But when I update it then shows it a error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in
>   /home/u301963782/domains/quickgroup.in/public_html/enquirybagnanedit1.php:57
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/u301963782/domains/quickgroup.in/public_html/enquirybagnanedit1.php(57):
>   mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE enqbagna...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/u301963782/domains/quickgroup.in/public_html/enquirybagnanedit1.php
>   on line 57

Here is my edit page code.

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");
include "config_1.php";
include "config.php";
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $pname=$_POST['pname'];
    $occu=$_POST['occu'];
    $ci=$_POST['ci'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $about=$_POST['about'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];    
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $phone2=$_POST['phone2'];
    $tn=$_POST['tn'];
    $tp=$_POST['tp'];
    $ta=$_POST['ta'];
    $tn2=$_POST['tn2'];
    $tp2=$_POST['tp2'];
    $ta2=$_POST['ta2'];
    $tn3=$_POST['tn3'];
    $tp3=$_POST['tp3'];
    $ta3=$_POST['ta3'];
    $otherd=$_POST['otherd'];
    $bb=$_POST['bb'];

    $instn=$_POST['instn'];
    $qual=$_POST['qual'];
    $stream=$_POST['stream'];

    $year=$_POST['year'];
    $cn=$_POST['cn'];
    $cf=$_POST['cf'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];


    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($name)  ) {            
        if(empty($name)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        // if(empty($zone)) {
        //     echo "<font color='red'>Zone field is empty.</font><br/>";
        // }

        // if(empty($email)) {
        //     echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br/>";
        // }        
    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE enqbagnan SET name='$name',pname='$pname',address='$address',occu='$occu',qual='$qual',ci='$ci',phone='$phone',phone2='$phone2',instn='$instn',about='$about',tn='$tn',tp='$tp',ta='$ta',tn2='$tn2',tp2='$tp2',ta2='$ta2',tn3='$tn3',tp3='$tp3',ta3='$ta3',fname='$fname',otherd='$otherd',date='$date',bb='$bb' WHERE id=$id");

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: editsuccessenqbagnan.html");
    }
}
?>
<?php
//getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM enqbagnan WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $name = $res['name'];
    $pname=$res['pname'];
    $occu = $res['occu'];
    $ci = $res['ci'];
    $address = $res['address'];
    $about=$res['about'];
    $fname=$res['fname'];    
    $phone=$res['phone'];
    $phone2=$res['phone2'];
    $tn=$res['tn'];
    $tp=$res['tp'];
    $ta=$res['ta'];
    $tn2=$res['tn2'];
    $tp2=$res['tp2'];
    $ta2=$res['ta2'];
    $tn3=$res['tn3'];
    $tp3=$res['tp3'];
    $ta3=$res['ta3'];
    $otherd=$res['otherd'];
    $bb=$res['bb'];

    $instn=$res['instn'];
    $qual=$res['qual'];





    $date=$res['date'];


    // $age = $res['age'];
    // $email = $res['email'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="" style="background-color: antiquewhite;  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
    <!--<a href="index.php">Home</a>-->
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="myform" action="enquirybagnanedit1.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform()">  
        <h1 align="center">YOUTH COMPUTER TRAINING CENTRE</h1>
        <h4 align="center">* fields are mandatory</h4>
         <hr>
                <table align="center">




              <tr>
                <td>Name: *</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder ="Enter name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td>Father/ Guardian's Name: *</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder ="Enter Guardian name" value="<?php echo $pname;?>"/></td>
              </tr> 

              <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder ="Enter Address" value="<?php echo $address;?>"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Occupation :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="occu" name="occu" placeholder ="Enter Occupation" value="<?php echo $occu;?>"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Last Academic Qualification:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="qual" name="qual" placeholder ="Enter Last Qualification" value="<?php echo $qual;?>"</td>
              </tr>

              <tr> 
                <td >Course Name :</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="ci">
               <option value="None" value="<?php echo $ci;?>">choose option </option>
               <option value="CITA (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> CITA (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="CFAS (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> CFAS (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="CDTP (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> CDTP (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="CCAD (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> CCAD (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="CCHM (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> CCHM (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="DITA (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DITA (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="DITA (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DITA (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="DFAS (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DFAS (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="DFAS (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DFAS (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="DDTP (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DDTP (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="DDTP (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DDTP (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="DCHM (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DCHM (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="DCHM (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> DCHM (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADITA (18 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADITA (18 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADITA (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADITA (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADITA (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADITA (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADFAS (18 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADFAS (18 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADFAS (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADFAS (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADFAS (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADFAS (6 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADDTP (18 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADDTP (18 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADDTP (12 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADDTP (12 Months) </option>
               <option value="ADDTP (6 Months)" value="<?php echo $ci;?>"> ADDTP (6 Months) </option>
           </select>

                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $ci;?></td>

            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Contact No :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder ="Enter Phone No." value="<?php echo $phone;?>"/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Another Contact No :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phone2" name="phone2" placeholder ="Enter another Phone No." value="<?php echo $phone2;?>"/></td>
              </tr>


                   <tr>
                       <td>If Others Teacher Name :</td>
                       <td><input type=text name="ta" placeholder="Enter Teacher Name" value="<?php echo $ta;?>"/></td>
                   <td><input type=text name="ta2" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" value="<?php echo $ta2;?>"/></td>
                   <td><input type=text name="ta3" placeholder="Enter Address" value="<?php echo $ta3;?>"/></td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                   <td> Friends :</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" name="about" value="FRIENDS" /></td>
                   <td><input type=text name="fname" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"/></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td> Others :</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" name="about" value="OTHERS" /></td>
                   <td><input type=text name="otherd" placeholder="Enter Details" value="<?php echo $otherd;?>"/></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td> Website :</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" name="about" value="WEBSITE" value="<?php echo $about;?>"/></td>
               </tr>



               <tr>
               <td> Date : *</td>
               <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>"/></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Counsellor Name *</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="bb" name="bb" placeholder ="Enter your name" value="<?php echo $bb;?>"/></td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td> I Agree :</td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" name="true" value="" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>



        </form>





    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that one of your `$_POST` variables has a single quote `'` in it...

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: So, it looks like you're putting single quotes (ASCII code 39, ') around the table and column names. In MySQL and MariaDB require that you use the backtick (ASCII code 96, `).

Answer (score 2):

Your problematic line is this one:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE enqbagnan SET name='$name',pname='$pname',address='$address',occu='$occu',qual='$qual',ci='$ci',phone='$phone',phone2='$phone2',instn='$instn',about='$about',tn='$tn',tp='$tp',ta='$ta',tn2='$tn2',tp2='$tp2',ta2='$ta2',tn3='$tn3',tp3='$tp3',ta3='$ta3',fname='$fname',otherd='$otherd',date='$date',bb='$bb' WHERE id=$id");
```

It's *one* very long line, and you're not catching the error that's coming from it. Try the following:

```
try { 
       $query = "UPDATE enqbagnan
SET name='$name',
    pname='$pname',
    address='$address',
    occu='$occu',
    qual='$qual',
    ci='$ci',
    phone='$phone',
    phone2='$phone2',
    instn='$instn',
    about='$about',
    tn='$tn',
    tp='$tp',
    ta='$ta',
    tn2='$tn2',
    tp2='$tp2',
    ta2='$ta2',
    tn3='$tn3',
    tp3='$tp3',
    ta3='$ta3',
    fname='$fname',
    otherd='$otherd',
    `date`='$date',
    bb='$bb'
WHERE id=$id";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query); 
   } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
      var_dump($e);
      exit; 
   }
```

And see if SQL gives you more readable error.

Comment: Yeah some SQL flavours like there to be a `;` at the end of a query. Glad we got it sorted!

Comment: I think Nick's suggestion must be correct.

Comment: @Strawberry, ah, yes, I fixed that.

Comment: And yes, please clean your user input before submitting to SQL.